# PHP 8 - Routing can't find requested URL

Tags: php, web, model-view-controller, routes

I have a problem with PHP 8 routing. I'm creating my MVC "framework" to learn more about OOP. I did routing, controller and view - it works, I'm happy. But I found out that I would test my creation. This is where the problem begins, namely if the path is empty (""), it returns the "Home" view as asked in the routing, but if I enter "/ test" in the URL, for example, I have a return message "404 Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server. " even though the given route is added to the table. What is wrong?

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php with routes

```
<?php

/*
 * Require Composer
 */
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php'; 

/*
 * Routing
 */

$routes = new Core\Router();

$routes->new('', ['controller' => 'HomeController', 'method' => 'index']);
$routes->new('/test', ['controller' => 'HomeController', 'method' => 'test']);

$routes->redirectToController($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Router.php file

```
<?php

namespace Core;

class Router
{

    /*
     * Routes and parameters array
     */
    protected $routes = [];
    protected $params = [];


    /*
     * Add a route to the route board
     */
    public function new($route, $params = [])
    {
        /* 
         * Converting routes strings to regular expressions 
         */
        $route = preg_replace('/\//', '\\/', $route);
        $route = preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\}/', '(?P<\1>[a-z-]+)', $route);
        $route = '/^' . $route . '$/i';

        $this->routes[$route] = $params;
    }


    /*
     * Get all routes from table
     */
    public function getRoutesTable() {
        return $this->routes;
    }


    /*
     * Checking if the specified path exists in the route table
     * and completing the parameters table
     */
    public function match($url)
    {

        foreach($this->routes as $route => $params) {
            
            if(preg_match($route, $url, $matches)) {
                foreach($matches as $key => $match) {
                    if(is_string($key)) {
                        $params[$key] = $match;
                    }
                }

                $this->params = $params;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    
    /*
     * Get all params from table
     */
    public function getParamsTable() {
        return $this->params;
    }


    /*
     * Redirection to the appropriate controller action
     */
    public function redirectToController($requestUrl) {
        $requestUrl = explode('?', $requestUrl);
        $url = $requestUrl[0];
        
        if ($this->match($url)) {
            $controller = $this->params['controller'];
            $controller = "App\\Controllers\\$controller";

            if(class_exists($controller)) {
                $controller_obj = new $controller($this->params);
                $method = $this->params['method'];

                if(method_exists($controller, $method)) {
                    $controller_obj->$method();
                } else {
                    echo "Method $method() in controller $controller does not exists!";
                }

            } else {
                echo "Controller $controller not found!";
            }

        } else {
            echo "No routes matched!";
        }
    }
}
```

View.php file

```
<?php

namespace Core;

class View {
    public static function view($file) {
        $filename = "../App/Views/$file.php";
        
        if(file_exists($filename)) {
            require_once $filename;
        } else {
            echo "View $file is not exist!";
        }
    }
}
```

HomeController file

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Core\Controller;
use Core\View;

class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        return View::view('Home');
    }

    public function test() {
        return View::view('Test');
    }
}
```

Folder structure

[image]

Routes in web browser

[image]

I'm using XAMPP with PHP 8.0 and Windows 10.

Comment: _"if I enter "/ test" "_ - Is the space in "/ test" in your question accidental? Otherwise it make sense that it doesn't match "/test" since those two strings are different.

Comment: Yes, there is my mistake in the question. "/test" is correct

Comment: I don't see how this works at all? `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` isn't the URL/path, it's only what comes after the `?` in the URL. For example: `https://example.com/test/?this-is-the-part-your-router-gets`

Comment: When i use ` 'REQUEST_URL' ` I have this same problem.

Comment: `REQUEST_URL` isn't a standard parameter afaik. You probably mean `REQUEST_URI`?

Comment: Yeah, just like you write. I am pensive about the problem and make stupid mistakes when I don't write code

Comment: Have you configured apache to allow htaccess files? The 404 page seems to be apaches default 404 page, which means that it never reached your code at all.

Comment: No, I haven't done any apache setup. But there is a .htaccess file that changes DirectoryIndex to the directory where index.php is with the new routes, so that wouldn't work either

Comment: _"But there is a .htaccess file that changes DirectoryIndex to the directory"_ - Do you have multiple htaccess files? Where is the one you posted here located? That needs to go in the root folder (overwriting the existing). Ah, you have yours _outside_ if the root folder. There it won't do any good. Replace the one in `/public` with yours.

Comment: Yes I have a lot of .htaccess files. One of them is directly in the htdocs/ folder and contains "DirectoryIndex Public/index.php", the other is in the htdocs/Public folder, and I published its contents in the question at the top

Comment: I moved the .htaccess file from the /Public folder to the root folder and also added "DirectoryIndex Public/index.php" in it. Unfortunately, the same problem continues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, choose one of the following two options to proceed.

**Option 1:**

If the *document root* is set to be the same as the *project root*, e.g. `path/to/htdocs`, in the config file of the web server (probably `httpd.conf`), similar to this:

```
DocumentRoot "/path/to/htdocs"   
<Directory "/path/to/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then create the following `.htaccess` in the *project root*, remove any `.htaccess` file from the directory `path/to/htdocs/Public` and restart the web server:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex /Public/index.php /Public/index.html
</IfModule>

Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

**Option 2:**

If the *document root* is set to be the directory `path/to/htdocs/Public` in the config file of the web server (probably `httpd.conf`), similar to this:

```
DocumentRoot "/path/to/htdocs/Public"   
<Directory "/path/to/htdocs/Public">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then create the following `.htaccess` in the directory `path/to/htdocs/Public`, remove any other `.htaccess` file from the *project root* (unless it, maybe, contains some relevant settings, other than `DirectoryIndex`) and restart the web server::

```
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

After you decided and proceeded with one of the options above, edit the page `index.php` as shown bellow:

```
<?php

//...

/*
 * NOTE: A route pattern can not be an empty string.
 * If only the host is given as URL address, the slash 
 * character (e.g. "/") will be set as value of the
 * URI path, e.g. of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Therefore, 
 * the route pattern should be set to "/" as well.
 */
$routes->new('/', [
    'controller' => 'HomeController',
    'method' => 'index',
]);

//...

/*
 * In order to get the URI path, you must use the server 
 * parameter "REQUEST_URI" instead of "QUERY_STRING".
 */
$routes->redirectToController(
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
);
```

**Notes:**

- In regard of changing `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, the credits go to @MagnusEriksson, of course.
- There can't be an *"MVC framework"*, but a *"web framework for MVC-based application(s)"*. This is, because a framework is just a collection of libraries (not at all correlated with MVC), which, in turn, is used by one or more applications implementing the MVC pattern.

For any further questions, don't hesitate to ask us.

Comment: Thanks for your help, comments and suggestions. I will be asking for sure!

The problem can be solved in 3rd way, namely in the Apache httpd.conf file search for "404", delete the comment next to the phrase "ErrorDocument 404" and provide the path to the folder where the "index.php" file or the .htaccess file is located referring to index

Comment: @FilipKrzyżanowski You are welcome. Ohh, this seems to be one of the most beautiful tricks in the world of programming :-)